# PHP array not displaying?

Tags: php, arrays

I cant get this code to display the array? I have got it to the stage to display "no more pages" but its not displaying the "prev" and "next" links.. Can anyone help please...

```
$url = array('index.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php', 'page5.php','page6.php', 'page7.php', 'page8.php'); 

$path = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$prev_link=$next_link='no more pages';

   foreach ($url as $key => $page)
 {
        if ($path == $page)
    {
         if (isset($url[$key-1]))
            $prev_link = "<a href=\"{$prev}\">prev</a>";
          if (isset($url[$key+1]))
            $next_link = "<a href=\"{$next}\">next</a>";
        }


    }

echo $prev_link . ' - ' . $next_link;
```

Comment: The variables `$prev` and `$next` are never defined, you might get an error because of that.

Comment: Did you check if the condition `if ($path == $page) { ... }` is working? Also, the variables `$prev` and `$next` aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: He said that he was able to get it to display "no more pages", so `$prev` and `$next` are probably defined somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @ElGavilan not true. He was getting that and because his evaluation returned 'false' so the interpreter never got there to throw the error.

Comment: @dops You're right, I misread his code...

Answer (score 0):

PHP_SELF will generally return a response with a leading forward slash so none of your example pages will match.

try

```
$path = str_replace ("/","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Also you are assigning empty variables to the link

```
$prev_link = "<a href=\"{$prev}\">prev</a>";
$next_link = "<a href=\"{$next}\">next</a>";
```

try

```
$prev_link = "<a href=\"{$url[$key-1]}\">prev</a>";
$next_link = "<a href=\"{$url[$key+1]}\">next</a>";
```

Hopefully this should work